# How can I create a shortcut in Drive that redirects to a specific url

Tags: python, google-drive-api, shortcut

I've been unsuccessfully trying to create a short cut in Drive that once you click on it, you get redirected to a specific url.

Do you have an idea on how I might do that?

Here is the code I started with :

```
  drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

  # Insert a shortcut

  body = {
      'title': 'shortcut',
      'description': 'description',
      'mimetype': 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk',
  }
  file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body).execute()
```

It created the file but when I click on it in Drive it redirects me here:

```
'https://docs.google.com/file/d/{File ID}/edit'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. This will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you, I hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the open location of a shortcut file owned by your app via the Open URL template in the developer console entry.

See these pages on integrating with the [Drive UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk).

Comment: To each shortcut there will be a specific redirection url. Basically what I want to do is to save URLs in drive, a bookmark of sorts.. is that possible ?

Comment: No.  Your app needs to have a open-url template for all shortcuts it can open.  You could conceivably store your own mapping from file id to url and do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You cant create a shortcut file unless is a custom file that opens by default by your previously-installed drive app.
Else you could create the html for the anchor and use that as the html content for agoogle doc. See the official docs on how to do that, basically you create a new google doc with that html and specify convert=true.

When the user opens the gdoc, she will need two more clicks to navigate to the url.